# Java Selector OP_READ not triggered if data is already available

Tags: java, nio

I am writing a NIO server that accepts a connection

```
serverSocketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
```

In order to create a race condition between the acceptation of the connection and the registration of `OP_READ`, lets assume that upon accept, the server waits `Thread.sleep(1000);` and then only registers the read

```
clientSocketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

Meanwhile, due to the delay, some client data has already been sent over the network and is available.

What I am experiencing is that the selector does NOT trigger `OP_READ` for this existing data and I have to force a read manually.
The `OP_READ` is then properly triggered for all subsequent incoming data.

Is this the normal behavior ? Why does it not trigger despite the fact that there are some data ready to be read ?

Comment: Never seen this since NIO came out. Why the pointless sleep? Remove it.

Comment: The sleep is not actually there, it is just to emphasis that there *might* be a delay. I have observed that race condition sometimes and it is horrible to troubleshoot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javadoc for `Selector` (and `SelectableChannel`) explains that `select()` calls on channels that "have become selectable since the previous selection operation", which to me implies that if there was no previous selection operation it checks the period since registration, and not before. Which means, yes, what you see is the expected behaviour.

That is also logical - the channel that has no interest registered in reads has no reason to track incoming data, and only when you register such an interest (that is, after you register the selector for `OP_READ`), it starts monitoring incoming data.

Bottom line is - you probably want to register selector straight away, and not wait for a second before registering.

If upon receiving OP_ACCEPT event you do something like:

```java
SocketChannel client = serverSocket.accept();
client.configureBlocking(false);
client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

you have pretty minimal chance for race, as the other end will have to:

1. figure out the connection accepted (that involves network hop),
2. write some data to the socket,
3. that data must pass through the network,

and all that in between your 2 calls to accept() and register(), none of which involves transferring data over the network. I would highly doubt it's realistic to get the (complete chuck of) data in between (NB: it should be a complete piece of data, otherwise some of it will come after register and hence will trigger the select).

Comment: It somehow makes sense, but there will always be a race condition between the accept and the read registration. This makes it mandatory to check after registration. Also, there is no guarantee that a `channel.read()` will read all data available which again forces to use a loop no matter what. I would have thought it would be more convenient to use :/

Comment: sorry comments formatting sucks, I'll put this as an update to the answer

Comment: No. It has to do with whether the underlying implementation uses edge triggering or level triggering. This is supposed to work. The real registration happens when you call `select()`: it isn't a prior even at all.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne so you confirm that if data is received _before_ `select()` it will not trigger reliably (depending on internal implementation) ?

Comment: @Simon I confirm that it's supposed to work, and that it's been working for me in a commercial product that has been out since 2005. This is the only reason I can think of why it wouldn't, but it would be a major implementation error, and break the world, and so it would be very surprising. What OS are you on? And what JDK?

Comment: @MarquisofLorne `WIN 10` with `GraalVM (JDK11)`. I am testing the server with brutal 1000 connections in parallel that fill the localhost TCP stack immediately but dont send anything more after that, this is also probably why this appears to never happen in real life. I have observed the issue only a few times for a lot of runs. Yet, it means that it seems to happen :(